# c# devexpress datagrid currentrow code

Tags: c#, datagrid

i have a problem with devexpress. i am new in devexpress and i dont know how to get devexpress's datagrid current row selection

i am trying to write something like this:
i couldnt get the "get row cell value" from dgwOpsiyonlar table

```
    int makinaId = (int)dgw_makinaOpsiyonlari.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value;
```

but i couldn't find any sample like this and it doesn't work which i found:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using DevExpress.Data;

 namespace elektrikProgrm
 {
public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.makinaIsimleriTableAdapter.Fill(this.formaMakinaDataSet.makinaIsimleri);
        connectionDataContext con = new connectionDataContext();

        dgwOpsiyonlar.DataSource = con.makinaIsimleris;

    }

    private void dgwOpsiyonlar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        object Value = dgwOpsiyonlar.GetRowCellValue("ColumnName", dgwOpsiyonlar.FocusedRowHandle );

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the DevExpress XtraGrid, there are two different "current rows" to distinquish between: the focused row and the selected rows.

- The focused row is the one with the active cell editor
- The selected rows are the one, which were selected by the user (when using
  multiselection for example.

You can get the focused row by accessing the `MyGridView.FocusedRowHandle` property ([see doc.](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic)), which is an int. DevExpress calls this a RowHandle - you might have to translate this RowHandle to the DataTable row or object list index of the grid's datasource later on (see below). The same is with the selected rows: you can get them by accessing `MyGridView.GetSelectedRows()` ([see doc.](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic)). These integer values are RowHandles as well.

#### Note that you call the GridView, not the GridControl!

Now that you have one or more RowHandles, you can get the corresponding datasource items by calling ...

```
MyObject obj = gridView.GetRow(rowHandle) as MyObject;
```

... if you bound a list of objects to the grid or ...

```
DataRow row = gridView.GetDataRow(rowHandle);
```

... to get the corresponding DataRow if you bound a DataTable.

This is the way you can work with you data objects directly. The other way you mentionend should work as well if you just want to have one certain cell value.

But I think you set the arguments in the wrong order, [the documentation says](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowCellValuetopic), that you first need your RowHandle and the column name or index as second argument.

So, just try this:

```
object Value = dgwOpsiyonlar.GetRowCellValue(dgwOpsiyonlar.FocusedRowHandle, "ColumnName");
```